# Google BigQuery Taking too Long, but small change

Tags: performance, google-bigquery, google-cloud-platform

One of the annoying features of BigQuery is its unpredictable behavior.

The last such annoyance can be illustrated in this query

```
SELECT 
COUNT(DISTINCT large_table.event_id ) AS large_table_count,
COUNT(DISTINCT small_table.pk) AS small_table_count
FROM large_table
LEFT JOIN small_table ON
  large_table.ga_user_id = small_table.ga_user_id
```

Where large_table ~2.5GB, and small_table is ~250mb

When I join on a ga_user_id, the query takes ~60 seconds. More importantly, it finishes and it the size of tables can be increased without a significant increase in time. (see screenshot 1).

When I join on a date string, however, the query's time shoots up to ~140 seconds. (see screenshot #2) More importantly, the performance does not scale linearly with data size. The query just does not finish even after 3,000 seconds.

A couple observations: 
1) snapshot_date has less variability than ga_user_id
2) Both ga_user_id and snapshot_date are strings

**What am I missing?**

[image]
[image]